# Prototype Chain Inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I'm wrapping my head about Prototype Chain under the hood but I'm having some difficulty building out a function. I want to build a function that will take in an object and add to the object's prototype. What am I doing wrong?

```
function getObject(obj) {
  function F() {}
  F.prototype.say = function(){
    console.log("Hello", this.name);
  }.bind(obj);

  obj.prototype = Object.create(F.prototype);
  return obj;
}

var r = getObject({ name: "James"});

r.name
r.say()

// r = { name: "James" } 
// r.say() "Hello James"
```

I got what I was looking for. I was limited and wasn't allowed to use ES6 classes... I know right?

```
function getObject(obj) {
  function F() { }
  F.prototype.say = function(){
    console.log("Hello", this.name);
  };
  const output = Object.create(F.prototype);
  return Object.assign(output, obj);
}

var r = getObject({ name: "James"});
r // { name: "James" }
r.name  // "James"
r.say() // "Hello James"
```

Comment: objects don't have a prototype property functions do. They only have a dunder proto linkage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified the code. Object do not have prototype. Functions have prototype that can be used for chaining. Hope this helps.

```
function getObject(obj) {
    function F() {}
    F.prototype = Object.create(obj);

    F.prototype.say = function(){
        console.log("Hello", this.name);
    }.bind(obj);

    return new F();
}

var r = getObject({ name: "James"});

console.log(r.name); // James
r.say() // Hello James
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

You can add methods to an object like `obj.something = function() {};`

As for method chaining, you want to return `this` inside your inherited function.

So something like this will answer your problem

```
function getObject(obj) {
    obj.say = function() {
        console.log(`Hello ${this.name}`);
        return this;
    }
    obj.hi = function() {
        console.log('hi');
        return this;
    }
    return obj;
}

var newObj = getObject({});

newObj.say().hi();
// Helo A K
// hi
```

Also you assign obj.prototypes to equal a Class, not the class prototypes. So in the future if you want to make one prototype to equal a class prototype use `obj.prototype = Object.create(anothingObj.prototype);`

Comment: new  f() is not a class. It may seem like a class behaviour but the new keyword is just creating an empty object .JS doesn' have classes

Comment: its not a class but it simulates a class. new keyword is not creating an empty object. `new F();` actually contains function `say`. By the way, JavaScript ES6 has classes.

Comment: new keyword is creating an empty object you can check the ECMAScript specificaions and the function F() is just pointing the this to the new empty object. And yes ES6 may have the class keyword but it doesn't mean JS have classes. It's just syntactic sugar. It's the same behaviour as the `new F() ` under the hood just a lot less code.

Comment: @4mohit thank you down voting my correct answer to the guy's question, but you didn't answer A K questions on how to do method chaining. So please be kind to research and then up vote my answer. Thank you.

Comment: I did answer his question mate.And yes your answer is incorrect. In your answer  `this.name` will always point to `A K `. Even if we pass a name property to the empty object. It's not about making the code work. In you case it not working. Nonetheless it's about how it's working under the hood. So please review your code again. You are welcome.

Comment: @4mohit ES6 provides better support for Object-oriented programming so you can do things like inheritance, Abstract, etc but you're correct about it being syntactic sugar. But you can say the same when you compile a Java Class. "it's just syntactic sugar". Get to reading http://2ality.com/2015/02/es6-classes-final.html

Comment: There's a lot of difference between ES6 class and Java class mainly because of the prototype chain.

Comment: in ES6 to "prototype chain", you use class2 extend class1. You don't say prototype. 
Keep exploring your "hello-react" app, you will find a lot of new things about ES6.

Comment: Well at least I can write correct code in my hello react app. Keep editing it. Maybe eventually you will get it right.
P.S- you might wanna edit `// Hello A K` too. Because it doesn't make sense now.

Comment: Why are you checking if Object.create exist? You know that's a global object, right? Why are you overriding Object create with your function? Object.create also defines the Object non-enumerable properties. Your code obviously isn't doing that, and you have a typo naming your function.

Comment: I'm not looking to add properties to my object. I'm looking to give it a prototype pointing to a new method.

Answer (score 1):

You are explicitly adding a prototype property on an object.`obj.prototype = undefined` and when you call it with the new keyword it will just add an empty object to that property. so the new obj will be `obj = {name:'james' , prototype: {}}`. Now the prototype property of the object will point to the functions F's prototype. The correct way to do this is by Object.create. You can imitate that same behaviour like this

```
 if(!Object.create){ 
 Object.create = function(o) { 
 function F() {} 
 F.prototype = o ;
  return new F(); 
 }; 
}
```

You can check out MDN [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) for the detailed explanation of the Object.create polyfill